# passing variables between methods in ROR controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, controller

In my controller I pass date from method create to method index. How can I pass it back from index to create (for new create)?

```
 def index  
   @date = params[:date].
 end

 def create
    <<<NEED to get @date from index here>>>
    @entry = Entry.new(:input => input, :user => current_user, :time => @date)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @entry.save
       format.html { redirect_to(:action => "index", :edit => true) }
     end
   end
```

Comment: What's the underlying thing that you are trying to do?  What you are describing doesn't make sense.  What if someone were to call your create method before calling index?  What if one user calls index and another one calls create?  HTTP is mostly stateless, so the idea that you are going to connect two separate controller actions screams design problems..

Comment: That's right. I just need to remember the last time selected by each user for that user. hidden variable seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to get it from `index`?

Keep it in a hidden form variable and submit it, etc. You can't get it from `index`.